# What does the butcher weigh?

Tags: riddle, lateral-thinking

A butcher is 6 feet tall and wears size 11 shoes. What does he weigh?

Hint:

> Think outside the box!!

Comment: Wow xD i guess you have to come up with a really unique idea; all off my questions take 44 seconds to answer

Comment: And most of those 44 seconds were spent coming up with a creative way to satisfy SE's answer criteria.

Comment: This riddle is very well known.

Comment: @WBT check out tim's answer below hahaha he uses a very "creative way to satisfy SE's answer criteria"...

Comment: You said "What does..." instead of "How much..."??

Answer (score 16, accepted):

After his diet, the butcher weighs

> Meat.

Comment: Is that you, [Kowalski](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ghRFG4oAtks)?

Answer (score 2):

The butcher weighs

> slaughtered animals

Answer (score 0):

> meat

He weighs a lot

> of meat

I used to work in a butcher shop

Is this 30 characters yet?

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling!  Please try to avoid posting answers that duplicate existing ones (in particular, WBT gave a very similar answer earlier today).

Answer (score -1):

everything:

> all the meat he sells